# T-SQL Best Fuzzy Match

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I half expect the answer for this to be "it's impossible", but I am wondering if there is a good way to match two nvarchar columns on a "best match" basis.

I have two Name columns from different applications. Each of these names is usually followed by a type code (I don't know or have access to what these type codes mean or map to) Here is an example:

```
Name1               Name2
Steven Smith 4Q     Steve Smith 4Q
Mark Cubs 2R        Mark Cubs 2R
Billy Idol 3W       Bily Idol 3W
AngelLuis 3W        Angel Luis 4W
Beth Ann 1T         Beth Ann Gray 1T
Phil Miller 4Q      Phil Miller 392 4Q
Dave Havok 39 8D    Dave Havok 8D
```

I am trying to do a merge statement where the ON clause uses the Names to match my tables, but because the names are not always close enough to be caught by an LIKE operator, I am hoping there is a better way. Currently I match using a LIKE clause, but it only matches a few of them. What I want is for it to find the "closest/best match".

For example if I have

```
Col1     Col2  
Alex     NULL
All      Allfonse
Steve    Steven
Billy    Bill
Ann      NULL
Carol    NULL
```

I would like to match "Al" to "Alex" because it is the closest option available that is not already taken by a better match.

Comment: It is possible just very brutal to do it in TSQL, why can't you do it on the application side? Or at list use something like Powershell or SSIS

Comment: This might help - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/string-comparisons-sql-metaphone-algorithm/?utm_source=SSC&utm_medium=pubemail